# expected â,â or â...â before numeric constant in cstructs

Tags: c++, struct, g++

```
#include"symapi.h"


int SymInit               (char                          * db_filename,
                           SYMINIT_ACCMODE_T               access_mode,
                           int                           * p_handle,
                           SYMAPI_CONNECTION_BLK_T       * cblk,
                           char                          * vendor_id)
{
return 0;
}
```

g++ -o symapi.o -c sym.cpp

sym.cpp:4: error: expected identifier before numeric constant

sym.cpp:4: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

I get the above errors when i compile this small piece of code. I dont have a clue on how to proceed. I have copied the function prototype from header and am trying to define it. my header file is really large. so uploaded it in google drive: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8NCZDm0ClHVWFM3Qm5wU0MwUE0/edit?usp=sharing
Please help

Comment: sorry my xterm had utf encoding.its actually single quote(')

Comment: I am using only c structs. So i dont think thats applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++ -E test.cpp` shows the following. `-E` stops with pre-processing.

```
# 2 "test.cpp" 2
int SymInitV(char * db_filename, SYMINIT_ACCMODE_T access_mode, int * p_handle, SYMAPI_CONNECTION_BLK_T * cblk, char * vendor_id, 0x07000393)
{
    return 0;
}
```

See the last param is a simple number, no datatype associated with it.

SysInit is a macro defined in the symapi.h which is substitued with the following macro

```
#define SymInit(f, a, h, cb, vid) SymInitV(f, a, h, cb, vid, SYMAPI_C_VERSION)
```

Instead try implementing the SymInitV function which takes the following declaration

```
int SymInitV(char * db_filename, SYMINIT_ACCMODE_T access_mode, int * p_handle, SYMAPI_CONNECTION_BLK_T * cblk, char * vendor_id, int version)
```